# Meeting gets expired after just 2 minutes of its creation in big blue button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service, bigbluebutton, meeting-request

This is my BigBlueService which creates meeting

```
module BxBlockClasses
  class BigBlueService

    def self.server
      if (ENV["BIGBLUEBUTTON_API_URL"] && ENV["BIGBLUEBUTTON_SECRET"])
        @server = BigBlueButton::BigBlueButtonApi.new(ENV["BIGBLUEBUTTON_API_URL"], ENV["BIGBLUEBUTTON_SECRET"])
      end
    end

    def self.create_klass_meetings(recordklass, class_title, options = {}, max_participants)
        options = {
          welcome: "Welcome!",
          dialNumber: "",
          logoutURL: "",
          maxParticipants: max_participants,
          voiceBridge: 12345,
          record: false,
          duration: 20,
        }.merge(options)

        if self.server.present?
          created_meeting = self.server.create_meeting(class_title, 
          class_title&.parameterize + "-" +"#{recordklass&.id}", options)
          created_meeting
        end
    end
  end
end
```

If I join the meeting within 30 seconds of creation it will work perfectly fine but if I join the meeting through the same meetingId it will give me below error:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<response>
<returncode>FAILED</returncode>
<messageKey>notFound</messageKey>
<message>We could not find a meeting with that meeting ID</message>
</response>
```

Is there any way that I can extend my meeting joining request timeout??